# Execute method from dynamically created button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically create a table with data and buttons acting as download links. On button click, I want a method to be called with arguments relevant to that individual button object.

```
foreach(var item in list_files) {
  TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
  file_table.Rows.Add(tRow);
  TableCell namecell = new TableCell();
  namecell.Text = item.name;
  tRow.Cells.Add(namecell);
  TableCell datecell = new TableCell();
  datecell.Text = item.uTC;
  tRow.Cells.Add(datecell);
  TableCell sizecell = new TableCell();
  sizecell.Text = item.size;
  tRow.Cells.Add(sizecell);

  Button downloadButton = new Button();
  downloadButton.Text = "Download";

  // code here to call a method named GetFile with two arguments from "item"
  // e.g b.onclick ( GetFile(item.a, item.b)) ;

  TableCell downloadlink = new TableCell();
  downloadlink.Controls.Add(downloadButton);
  tRow.Cells.Add(downloadlink);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in list_files)
{
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
    file_table.Rows.Add(tRow);
    TableCell namecell = new TableCell(); namecell.Text = item.name; tRow.Cells.Add(namecell);
    TableCell datecell = new TableCell(); datecell.Text = item.uTC; tRow.Cells.Add(datecell);
    TableCell sizecell = new TableCell(); sizecell.Text = item.size; tRow.Cells.Add(sizecell);

    Button downloadButton = new Button();
    downloadButton.Text = "Download";
    downloadButton.Click += (sender, evnt) =>
    {
       //do stuff here
       GetFile(item.a, item.b)
    };

    // code here to call a method named GetFile with two arguments from "item"
    // e.g b.onclick ( GetFile(item.a, item.b)) ;

    TableCell downloadlink = new TableCell(); downloadlink.Controls.Add(downloadButton); tRow.Cells.Add(downloadlink);
}
```

Comment: You can use += and tab twice to have it create a handler or do it in place. I preferred doing it in place when using web forms to maintain scope. Variables inside of your loop can be used in the body of the click event that way.

Comment: Stephen,

This does not work, below is what I have and at no point is the "log" called to even detect a button press.  When the button is pressed the application restarts.  GetFile(a,b) simply contains another log remark at the moment.  I have edited the above post at the bottom with further information.